# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: php, jquery

Возникла проблема с Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$data = "count";
$number = 1;
if($data == "count")
    if (is_int($number)){
        echo json_encode(['status' => 1, 'count' => $number);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 0, 'count' => 0]);
    }
?>
```

Почему выдает ошибку 500 и как решить проблему? (делаю запрос через `$.post`)

```
$.post('http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/count.php',function(response){
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  switch (response['status']){
  case 1:
  $.each(response,function(key,val){
      if (key ==="count"){
          groupcount = parseInt(val);  }
  });
  break;
  case 0:
  console.log('Произошла ошибка');
  break;
} 
});
```

Comment: а `post` как выглядит?

Comment: <code>$.post('http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/count.php',function(response){
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  switch (response['status']){
      case 1:
      $.each(response,function(key,val){
          if (key ==="count"){
              groupcount = parseInt(val);  }
      });
      break;
      case 0:
      console.log('Произошла ошибка');
      break;
  }
});</code>

Comment: у вас не хватает `]`  в массиве.... но об этом уже вам написали в ответе

Comment: спасибо не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

синтаксическая ошибка

```
json_encode(['status' => 1, 'count' => $number);
// нужно 
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'count' => $number));
```

и включи вывод ошибок и в лог стоит заглянуть

Comment: Да достаточно `]` у массива в конце добавить))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский И потом думать где это масив, и где это if работает а где не работает. array сразу видно.

Comment: Почему-то `javascript'у` это не мешает. И не зря это ввели в php 5.4. не находите? не потехи ради ведь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на это возражу лишь одним, встречал мастеров которые пишут строки в 200 символов, незакрывают if и foreach, используют шот теги и @. После такого думаешь сколько надо выпить штоб так писать. синтаксис должен быть оправдан это рас, да и приложение должно быть обратно совместимо. т.е. тут мы привязываем приложение к 5.4 а заказчик грубо говоря, юзает 5.3 что делать? переписывать только приложение... Вот по этому и существую стандарты написания и документирования кода php. Что бы этот код жил а не стал чем то вроде кучей непонятных символов.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да и js не тот язык с которым стоит сравнивать.

Comment: `возражу лишь одним, встречал мастеров которые пишут строки в 200 символов, незакрывают if и foreach, используют шот теги и @` >>> причем тут короткий синтаксис объявления массива непонятно...`привязываем приложение к 5.4 а заказчик грубо говоря,юзает 5.3 что делать?` >>>для этого с заказчиком обговариваются детали под названием ТЗ и технические детали, в том числе где указывается необходимая версия всех используемых ресурсов, а не где исполнитель от балды берет его любимые  :-D Ткните пальцем в стандарт где написано избегать объявления массива через `[]` и только `array()` и баста :-D