# Считать json в php и вывести на экран

Tags: php, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
    "name": "Matematuka",
    "kabinet": 54,
    "time: "8:30-9:50",
    "teacher": "Panasyuk Galyna Volodymyrivna"
}
```

и PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $json = file_get_contents("test.json");
    echo $json;
?>
```

Вопрос: как вывести на экран текст файла `test.json`?

Comment: Так вы же это уже сделали. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: выводит пустоту

Comment: Что в логе ошибок?

Comment: понять бы где он

Comment: На экран - эту куда именно?

Comment: на веб страницу

Comment: а файл находится в той же директории что и `php` ?

Comment: а из вашего предыдущего вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482340/access-control-allow-origin  никак не связано с тем что вы отдаете это в `ajax` или щас напрямую даже не работает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский CWD далеко не обязательно совпадает с местоположением скрипта (что и может быть причиной ошибки автора в данном случая)

Comment: @Etki я малообразованный человек. скажите мне, что такое CWD ))

Comment: это все в одной директории

Comment: Лог ошибок в студию. Иначе это конкурс телепатов какой-то!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так вот же телепаты. пригласим их http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482462/cron-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82#comment556585_482462

Comment: @МиколаКікець Короч вам говорят, что надо не `"time: "8:30-9:50",`, а вот так: `"time": "8:30-9:50",`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский current working directory, текущая рабочая директория скрипта

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эмм... Ну да ладно...
Для начала json должен быть валидный

```
{"name": "Matematuka",
"kabinet": 54,
"time": "8:30-9:50",
"teacher": "Panasyuk Galyna Volodymyrivna"
}
```

Вообщем если надо просто получить данные с файлика json на том же сервере то

```
$j = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.json' ); // в примере все файлы в корне
$data = json_decode($j);
```

Если же есть 2 сайта "А" и "Б" и на "Б" нужно отдать файлик json то для "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" навешивать PHP смысла нету.
Если сервер под апачем создаем скажем папку "json" ложим туда .htaccess с таким содержимым ( mod_headers Apache должен быть включен )

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
AddType application/json .json
```

В эту же папку ложим наш json файлик

Получаем данные на сайте "А" с сайта "Б"

PHP

```
$j = @file_get_contents('http://mysiteb.com/json/data.json');
$data = json_decode($j);
```

Ну и выводим самым топорным методом

```
if( $j != false && !is_null($data)){
    foreach($data as $k => $e){
        echo '<p>'  . $e . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Можно так же получить аяксом ( jQuery в примере)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://mysiteb.com/json/data.json',
    dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(j) {
        console.log(j);
        var str = '';
        for(var i in j){
            str += '<p>' + j[i] + '</p>';
        }
        $('.json_info').html(str);
    })
})
</script>
<div class="json_info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у вас JSON невалидный.

> Error: Parse error on line 4: ...et": 54, "time: "    8: 30 - 9: 50 ",    "t
>   ---------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'NUMBER'

Во-вторых, пропишите нормально путь к файлу. Скорее всего, дело в этом

Comment: При использовании кода из вопроса, валидность json структуры не имеет значения

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести на страницу, где уже есть HTML:

```
<?php
  $j = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.json' ); 
  $data = json_encode(json_decode($j), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  echo '<pre>' . $data . '</pre>';
?>
```